# Finding Div present inside the data list on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datalist

I need to find the div which belongs my current clicked Link button from the code behind file in c#. Then i need to apply the class for that div. So far i tried to access by html table cell. But i cant able to access my div. So please any valuable suggestion to find the div?

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" style="width:100%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div runat="server" id="DivContent" style="padding-top: 25px; height: 65px;"  align="center"
                                onmouseover="this.className='MsgClick'" onmouseout="this.className=''" >
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' CommandName="show"
                                    class="InnerMenuFont"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AdminId") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <hr style="width: 80%" /> 

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
```

In the above code i need to access the current div in the id "DivContent"

```
.MsgClick
        {
            background-image: url('Images/AdminHighlight.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-right: -38px;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }
```

above code is my class file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560217/find-control-in-datalist Will this help you?

Comment: @ Freebird: ya but i need to access div. Div needs assembly reference in code behind file. But label is asp: control. That's y i am in struggle.

Comment: What do you mean by your div needs assembly reference?

Comment: Please considered the code that refer by you. In that the Label gets blue color while typing. Because it is a asp control. But div is not a asp control na?

Comment: Ok On what event do you want to access your div?

Comment: When clicking my link button present in that data list control. I need to change the class of the div. This is my requirement.

Comment: @freebird: Is it possible dude?

Comment: Let me try I will let you know in few mins.

Comment: @ArunKumarT I had implement this few times, what you need to do is assign some unique class for every div. example primary key to div like <div  '<%# "class=CL_'" Eval("ID") + "'" %>' runat="server".. SO every div is unqiuely identifier. Then in the row command call use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page) , "key" , "$('.CL_"+ ID  +"').addClass('MsgClick')" , true); The ID you get it somehow using COmmandArgument etc.. For this you need jquery reference like <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @KSaini: I tried to give unique id ourself please refer this following code <div runat="server" id='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' style="padding-top: 25px; height: 65px;"  align="center"
                            onmouseover="this.className='MsgClick'" onmouseout="this.className=''" > But it shows as error in create control msg.

Comment: Error Creating Control - DataList1The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" /> This is the error message

Comment: @ArunKumarT Please give unique class and using jquery assign the class

Comment: @KSaini: now i attached my unique class. I wont use any jquery. I am trying to access via code behind file when the link button get fired.

Comment: @ArunKumarT What i am trying to say you is that in the code behind you call call the javascript function that will executed when the page loaded again after postback. SO if you call the function that i specified in the previous comments then calling this javascript function will add the css class to the element uniquely identified by class

Comment: This you can call in code behind ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page) , "key" , "$('.CL_"+ ID +"').addClass('MsgClick')" , true);

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
Control objDiv = e.Item.FindControl("DivContent");
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong, but I don't believe it's possible to access a div from code behind if the div is part of a data bound control (DataList, GridView, etc), even if you have runat="server" set.

You can however swap the div for asp:Panel - which renders as a div when the page is served up to the browser. e.g.

```
<asp:Panel ID="DivContent" runat="server">
    div content... LinkButton, Label etc...
</asp:Panel>
```

When the LinkButton is clicked, you can find the asp:Panel in your code behind using the item index of the DataList to which the LinkButton belongs:

LinkButton OnClick event:

```
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the Link Button which has been clicked.
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    // Get the DataListItem in the DataList which contains the LinkButton which was clicked.
    DataListItem listItem = (DataListItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    // Get the ItemIndex of the DataListItem.
    int itemIndex = listItem.ItemIndex;
    // Find the asp:Panel in the DataListItem of the DataList (e.g. DataList1).
    Panel currentPanel = (Panel)DataList1.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("DivContent");
}
```

You should then hopefully be able to change style settings form code behind. 
You could possibly use the CssClass property to change what you need:

```
...
Panel currentPanel = (Panel)DataList1.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("DivContent");
currentPanel.CssClass = "NewClassName";
```

Comment: A div can be referenced as HtmlGenericControl from c# codebehind as long as it has an ID and runat = "server"

Answer (score 0):

Just did this myself good sir. There is a much simpler solution!

From your c# code behind, a div would be refereed to as type `HtmlGenericControl`.

You will need to add a `onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound"` to your DataList control markup.

Inside your itemdatabound event you can modify the div.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Find the div control as htmlgenericcontrol type, if found apply style
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div =  (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("DivContent");

    if(div != null)
        div.Style.Add("border-color", "Red");

}
```